# How to remove Alt+F7 window moving hot-key in Xubuntu?

Tags: shortcut-keys, xubuntu, xfce

I'd like to use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> to search for files in `Double Commander`.

But when I press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> - the hotkey is intercepted and I am offered to move the window.
`Settings - Settings manager - Keyboard - Application shortcuts` doesn't show <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> to be bound to anything.

Where can I undefine <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> hot key then?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

*Settings - Window Manager - Keyboard*

[image]

Double Click the short cut field and choose the key-combination you want

[image]

Comment: In 14.04 it is just (System) Settings -> Keyboard. Or use dash search to find "keyboard" (in your language) then move to tab "shortcuts".

Comment: No window shortcuts show on my 14.04 machine under System Settings > Keyboard.

Comment: @LeeMeador see here: http://imageshack.com/a/img540/5869/kRt010.png

Comment: For Ubuntu 18.04 Use Settings -> Devices -> Keyboad and find "Move Window" in the list of the shortcuts.